# How can I map the '<' key in vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to create the map

```
:map <F2> :map <F12> etcetcmy_map
```

which would have the result of: when I hit `<F2>`, the string `map <F12> etcetcmy_map` is typed into my console. but I'm having problems mapping the `<` key/char. Most pointedly, this is not being done; the string isn't being typed into my console. What happens instead is the the char under the cursor is case fliped (from upper to lower and vice versa) and then the cursor is moved forward by 1 char.

I've tried reading the documentation and have tried the Ctrl-V method, but I'm not getting it right. Does anyone how to do this, or if it is possible?

Comment: What are your problems? The mapping above should work without problems, although I'd use `:noremap` instead of `:map` in this case.

Comment: @Mhinz: (I've also editted the question) Well, it's just not being done. It seems that the '<' is not being read as a printable character... It worked once, and then every other time I've had this case flipping issue

Comment: What mode are you in at the time of keying in `F2`? Does `:nnoremap <F2> :nnoremap <F12> foobar` work in normal mode?

Comment: The symptoms you're reporting are characteristic of your terminal's escape sequences not matching up with what vim is expecting. What terminal application are you using, and what is `$TERM` set to?

Comment: @duskwuff: Sorry, I'm new(er) to linux and am not totally sure what you mean.

But I think the answers to your questions respectively are
Bash (response to ps -p $$) & 
ansi (response to echo $TERM)

@ mhinz: I'm in command. changing to noremap doesn't seem to work in either insert or command mode I'm afraid...

Comment: Why the hell would you want to map something to map something?

Comment: @romainl because you want the option to type in different flags before setting f12 to map to that thing

Comment: Why don't you simply `:map <F12> etcetcmy_map`? I smell a strong XY Problem fragrance, here. Could you explain why you want to create a mapping to create a mapping in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just googled XY problem and my response is... maybe. Ok, here's what I want
`:map <F2> :map <F12> :!gcc -o myexe % && ./myexe` but I want to be able to sometimes set the `-Wall` or `-lm` flags

Comment: @C.E.Sally: I meant what terminal application you're using (if any), not what shell. No matter what it is, though, `ansi` is almost certainly the wrong setting for `$TERM`.

Answer (score 1):

In your mapping's right-hand side, the `<F12>` is executed as a key press of the <kbd>F12</kbd> key (with the unexpected side effects you've described), but you want a literal insertion of the string `<F12>`. For that, escape the `<` char as `<lt>`:

```
:map <F2> :map <lt>F12> etcetcmy_map
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Unforunately this is not working =(

1) I just tried `:map <F2> :<lt>`
2) I can't find the corresponding notation for ">" I tried <gt> and <mt>

Comment: There is no corresponding `<gt>`; only the start needs to be escaped, as the `>` has no special meaning in mappings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map <kbd>F12</kbd> to `etcetcmy_map` when you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, you can:

```
:map <F2> :map <F12> etcetcmy_map<cr>
```

Comment: Do you mean map `F12` to a specific key when press `F2`?

Comment: I'm looking to get this `:map <F2> :map <F12> :!gcc -o myexe % && ./myexe` typed into my console when I hit `F2` because I want to be able to sometimes set the `-Wall` or `-lm` flags and then map that to `F12`

Comment: If you use `:map <F2> :map <F12> :!gcc -o myexe % && ./myexe` you will get: `:map <F12> :!gcc -o myexe % && ./myexe`, when you hit `F2`, is this you want?

Comment: That is what I want, but unfortunately that is not what I am getting. Duskwuff in the comments on the question seems to think it's not because of vim, but rather my os settings.

Comment: Maybe, I've try this on GVim and linux, both ok.